# Dynamic JSON string from jQuery AJAX return

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

In a `success` AJAX return I am trying to loop through an new array (`traits`), and used each item from that array for a new data string to get individual items from the AJAX returned array. So I need to dynamically look for `data.trait_return.background_path`, `data.trait_return.face_path`, `data.trait_return.body_path` etc. How to I make the `var trait_path` dynamic to work in the JSON `data` return string to look it an item from the returned JSON array? Right now I tried var `trait_path = trait + "_path";` with no luck. Hope that makes sense.

```
$.ajax({
        url         : 'start.php',
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : form_data,
        dataType    : "JSON",
        success     : function (data) {

            var traits = ["background","face","body","back","ears","head","bandana","legs"];
            $.each(traits, function(index, trait) {
                var trait_path = trait + "_path";
                alert(trait_path);
                $('#'+trait+'_select').val(data.trait_return.trait_path).prop("selected", "selected");
            })
        }
})
```

Comment: `data[\`trait_return.${trait}_path\`]`

Comment: that comes back as 'undefined' ?

Comment: Show and actual example object and I might be able to fix that